# C#, узнать время работы процесса по его имени

Tags: c#, процесс

Решил написать первую утилиту на C# по закрытию процесса, работающего слишком долго

```
foreach (var process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(process))
                    {                              
                        if(/*ВРЕМЯ ЖИЗНИ ПРОЦЕССА*/>10000)
                            process.Kill();
                    }
```

Каким методом можно получить информацию о времени, прошедшем с момента запуска процесса `process` с целью его уничтожения по превышению времени (10000 мс, например)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объекты `Process` имеют свойство [`StartTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.starttime?view=netframework-4.8). Можно использовать так:

```
if ((DateTime.Now - process.StartTime).TotalMilliseconds > 10000)
    process.Kill();
```